# How to chain signal producers or sequence of signal producers using reactive cocoa 5 or 6?

Tags: swift, cocoa, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa, reactive-swift

I am pretty much noob in ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift. I have two SignalProducers. If first SignalProducer returns nil, then I want to execute second Signal Producer otherwise not. I read the documentation, but I am not sure which syntax helps me to work something like this. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with "returns nil"? Do you mean that the first SignalProducer sends an Event with value nil? Or do you mean it does not send an Event at all and then terminates?

Comment: first producer sends an event with the value nil @MeXx

Answer (score 6):

Ok, so you want to take values from the first SignalProducer as long as these values are not nil. Then, you want to take values from the second SignalProducer. If phrased this way, it already tells you which operators you need: `take(while:)` and `then`:

```
let producerA: SignalProducer<Int?, NoError>
let producerB: SignalProducer<Int?, NoError>

...

producerA
  .take(while: { $0 != nil })
  .then(producerB)
```

The `take(while:)` operator will just forward all events as long as the given block returns true. So in this case, as soon as an event is nil, the block returns false and the resulting SignalProducer completes.

The `then` operator also forwards events from `producerA` until `producerA` completes, at which point `producerB` is started and now events from `producerB` are forwarded.